# How to make button back to home like back action bar?

Tags: android

I want to make button back with single click and not double page when i exit app. This is my code :

```
btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnOk.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent(Tentang.this,MainActivity.class));
            finish();

        }
    });
```

when i use that code and i press ok , system give me back , but when i press exit app system close and show Home page. I hope someone can help me . Thank you ..

Comment: you are using btnok for finish your activity right ? If this your last activity then it automatically exit. what is this issue not clearly understand

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean. Where is the `Tentang.class` from? Intent will create new `MainActivity.class`. If the `Tentang.class` from `MainActivity.class`, using Intent you will have 2 `MainActivity.class`. When you press back button, the app will close one `MainActivity.class` and show another `MainActivity.class`. You will need press 2 times to close the app.

Comment: @Saveen : im sorry if u not understand about my problem , my problem solved , thanks

Comment: @HoangNguyen : sorry my friend if u not understand , now my problem solved , the point my app became duplicate when i press back and close app. Thank you :)

Comment: @Brewh okie that great (Y)

Comment: @Brewh Ah, Ok. I'm glad that your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

hi don't know exactly what you are looking for but here is **onBackPressed** override method you can use,

```
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {

        finish();
    }

    this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```